# Ubuntu 12.10 boots to black screen after reinstallation in dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I'm new to using Ubuntu and have just bought a HP Pavilion g6-2240sa with Windows 8 pre installed.

I made a bootable USB with Ubuntu on it and installed alongside Windows, and for 2 days it worked fine. I got into Ubuntu by doing an advanced restart from Windows 8 and then booting Ubuntu from the partition it made.

When I did the advanced restart today there was only 1 HDD I could select (there were 3 before: Windows, a restore partition that was already there when I got the computer, and Ubuntu) so I booted from the USB again and re-installed Ubuntu. Then I did an advanced restart and the 3 partitions where there again, so I booted from Ubuntu and now here's my problem.

I get the Ubuntu background when its loading then its just a black screen with some writing, its not on long enough to read, then just a black screen with a white _ and the top left corner that does nothing. I have to restart the computer and it auto boots into Windows 8.

I'm a little confused as the first time I installed Ubuntu it worked fine until the partition disappeared), and the second time I installed I did everything the same except it found the old Ubuntu so I reinstalled it and now is doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to delete Ubuntu from that partition and then re-install it with a bootable USB

You can look online for resources on how to delete Ubuntu while running Windows.

Comment: i just booted again from the USB and this time selected delete ubuntu and reinstall, it work and i can now get to it from windows 8 advanced restart, still not from system boot up but i can still get to in non the less. hopfully it will last this time, still not sure why it stopped working in the first place tho!!

Comment: :3 I am just shocked that I got the answer even though my answer was close to nothing of the real result that needed to be done

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside Windows go to **My Computer**
2. Find your HDD and then go to the Ubuntu's partition
3. And then you just have to completely erase it from your computer.

That's what I did and it worked